# Decision trees for anomaly detection

Tags: clustering, random-forest, cart, anomaly-detection

**Problem**

From what I understand, a common method in anomaly detection consists in building a predictive model trained on non-anomalous training data, and perform anomaly detection using the error of the model when predicting on the observed data. This method requires the user to identify non-anomalous data beforehand.

- What if it's not possible to label non-anomalous data to train the model?
- Is there anything in literature that explain how to overcome this issue?

I have an idea, but I was wondering if someone has heard for something similar before, and could point me to the right direction (link papers/blogs, or explain existing methods).

**Idea**

I'd like to train a decision tree on a dataset $X$ with $N$ rows, $p$ columns, having a real valued target variable $Y$ (it's a regression problem). The dataset $X$ contains both anomalous and non-anomalous objects. The decision tree training process generates groups of objects, splitting the dataset iteratively along one dimension, at each iterations. The decision trees during prediction assigns an object to a specific leaf node. Each leaf node will have a certain distribution of values of the target variable Y. An anomalous object in this problem it's the one which doesn't perform well, more precisely an object for which Y is too low.

- Can I use the distribution in a leaf node to perform anomaly detection?
- Assuming that a bigger value for Y is preferred, can I say that the entities in the lowest 5th percentile of Y in a node are outliers?

**Example**

The decision tree assigns to the node j the objects following the rule: $2 <= x_1 < 4$ and $5 <= x_2 < 7$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two columns of the dataset. If I run a prediction on the entire dataset, the values of Y in the node j have have a gaussian distribution (mean=25, std=3), and I consider the values with $Y < 20.5$ outliers. The idea is that objects with $x_1$ and $x_2$ within a range, should perform similarly, and never below a target value.

**Considerations**

*First of all, I can see that this problem can be generalized to other methods. However, I find decision trees easier to explain here, moreover, I find the hard clustering property of trees useful for my problem, as I also need to cluster objects together.
*Second, I can see the issue of training the model with both anomalous and non-anomalous data. Though, I'm wondering whether due to some property, with a big amount of data, the leaf node's distribution move's toward the optimal (value of Y of the non-anomalous objects). But I guess this depends on the ration between anomalous vs non-anomalous objects.

Any hint in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use the distribution in a leaf node to perform anomaly detection?

Yes, in principle you can, but it might not be a good idea to use terminal-node-specific distributions to define outliers. Selected splits can be unstable, and thereby the minima, maxima, 1st and 3rd quartiles of the distributions in the terminal node, too.

> Assuming that a bigger value for Y is preferred, can I say that the entities in the lowest 5th percentile of Y in a node are outliers?

No. Unless you want to have 5% of observations classified as outliers, by default. A general (and probably more appropriate) rule-of-thumb for defining outliers is based on the inter-quartile range (IQR), according to which all values below Q1-1.5*IQR and Q3+1.5IQR would be outliers.

It sounds a bit like you are reinventing residual analysis. Why not compute residuals ($\hat{y} - y$), and inspect the distribution of those values to see if there are outliers (e.g., using the IQR-based rule above)? IMHO, such checking of residuals should be performed after fitting any predictive model.

Answer (score 0):

Existing data is usually assumed to be non-anomalous, not labeled. One can have a bit of anomalous data in there as well without too much of an issue (*contamination*). Some anomaly detection algorithms allows to specify an estimate of the ratio of contamination. For example in scikit-learn [IsolationForest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) or [LocalOutlierFactir](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html).